# How to change white background color of zathura?

Tags: pdf, zathura

I want to change the white background color in zathura pdf reader.

I've tried for example

```
:set default-bg \#6db46
```

but only the corners change into green.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I use "inverse color" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>r</kbd>).
Then change the dark black color to gray with `:set recolor-lightcolor \#222222`.

EDIT:
I have dark background with dark borders after using those commands (defaults to inverted)

```
set recolor   
set recolor-lightcolor \#222222
set recolor-keephue
set default-bg \#222230
```

So you might want to try default-bg or light-color ones.